# How to open a application using batch file and login to application using username and password

Tags: batch-file

Am trying to create a batch file using notepad to open an application ex.Quality Centre.
How can i login to it using the  user name and password.i.e. i want a single batch file that will open application as well as login into it.
Is that possible??
Because i have created a batch file to open a application, but i have to login manually.
Am new into creating batch files. So hope anyone can help me :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a hybrid like this.
It sends the username/password via `sendkey`, but it is necessary that your application has the focus.

```js
@if (@X)==(@Y) @goto :Dummy @end/* Batch part
@echo off
Setlocal
set "username=Fritz"
set "password=my secret"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" "%username%" "%password%"') do rem
goto :EOF

Jscript part */
var user=WSH.Arguments(0);
var pwd=WSH.Arguments(1);
var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WSH.Sleep(500);
sh.sendkeys(user+'\r\n');
WSH.Sleep(500);
sh.sendkeys(pwd+'\r\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the application will present a form for you to enter the username/password. In that case you will not be able to do what you want unless the application allows that information to be sent from the command line.

Some applications will allow parameters to be set. Try the documentation or just run the application with: --help or -h or /h or /help or /? and see if the application will tell you the parameters that it accepts.

Comment: Hi gfelisberto
I think its not possible. i tried it. Anyways thanks for the response.

Comment: You could send the username/password with JScript SendKey from a hybrid batch script