# Half Working batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a half working batch file, about opening 2 skypes with logging automatically.

The 1st skype opens and logs in, and the 2nd one opens with the 2nd username, but does not log in.

Any Ideas?

```
@ECHO OFF
color 3
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
@echo Skype One Starting
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /username:WRITE /password:WRITE
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
@echo Skype Two Starting
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary /username:WRITE /password:WRITE
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
```

Comment: Does the second `echo` command run?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd command run , it starting the 2nd skype , it does change to the 2nd user name , but doesn't log in.

Comment: im assuming the parameters `username` and `password` are parameters solely to skype when being used from the command line?

Comment: I tried it as well it opens the .exe and enters the details but does not log in

Comment: Check out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103717/how-to-open-a-application-using-batch-file-and-login-to-application-using-userna)